# Error while executing checkout script in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

[404-Not found]

Hello All,

I'm running one script having Checkout functionality but my script gets fail at particular page instance giving me "404 - Not found" error in logs.

But while executing manually I'm able to go to the page successfully.
Below is the error message. Do i need to pass cookies in the same while execution.

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: "404-Not Found" is not related to Cookies. It means the resource you are requesting does not exist. Compare the requests that are sent by browser (F12 -> Network tab, visit the page manually) and by JMeter (using View Results Tree Listener, replay the script). Share the screenshots of both (browser and JMeter) of that request.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely this is due to missing or not properly working [correlation](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/advanced-load-testing-scenarios-jmeter-part-1-correlations). You can record the test scenario using [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) but it will be only a "skeleton" of the test containing hard-coded values like IDs or URLs or whatever.

So given you checked something out and recorded the relevant request(s) next time you will try to replay the recorded script you will get an error as the item has already been checked out, so basically you need to find another one to work with.

Normally the situation is worked around as follows:

1. Record the test 2 times
2. Identify request parameters which are changing
3. Using [JMeter PostProcessors](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors) (the most commonly used is [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor), however it may vary depending on your response data nature) convert hard-coded recorded values into [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html)
4. Use [Debug Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler) and [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener combination to inspect:

   - JMeter Variables values
   - Request details
   - Server responses